# Python web-scraping error - TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, web-scraping, findall

I want to build a web scraper. Currently, I'm learning Python. This is the very basics!

Python Code

```
import urllib.request
import re

htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://basketball.realgm.com/")

htmltext = htmlfile.read()
title = re.findall('<title>(.*)</title>', htmltext)

print (htmltext)
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 201, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object in re.findall()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019854/typeerror-cant-use-a-string-pattern-on-a-bytes-like-object-in-re-findall)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to decode your data. Since the website in question says

```
charset=iso-8859-1
```

use that. utf-8 won't work in this case.

```
htmltext = htmlfile.read().decode('iso-8859-1')
```

Comment: This worked, but I'm still confused why we had to put a decode('iso-8859-1'). Are there sites that wouldn't require that addition?

Comment: @Jtwa check the source code of the site you are trying to scrape for `charset=...`. For the site in your question, the charset is iso-8859-1. If none is given, your best bet would usually be utf-8.

Answer (score 3):

Use bytes literal as pattern:

```
title = re.findall(b'<title>(.*)</title>', htmltext)
```

or decode the retrieved data to string:

```
title = re.findall('<title>(.*)</title>', htmltext.decode('utf-8'))
```

(change `utf-8` with appropriate encoding of the document)