# re.search().TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import urllib.request
import re

f = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.geekynu.cn/')
html = f.read()

title = re.search('<title>(.*?)</title>', html)
print(title)
#print(title.decode('utf-8')) //I had try to solve by this code.
```

[python 3.5] when I use `re.search()`to read the Web title,the error is hapen"TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object", what should I do? THX!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object in re.findall()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019854/typeerror-cant-use-a-string-pattern-on-a-bytes-like-object-in-re-findall)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`re` needs byte patterns (not string) to search bytes-like objects. Append a `b` to your search pattern like so: `b'<title>(.*?)</title>'`

Answer (score 5):

If you could add `html=html.decode('utf-8')`, I think it will be ok.

Comment: This answer is especially useful compared to the accepted answer, when the same regex needs to be used on both strings and files (bytes-like objects).