# what format is used for aws logs stored in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to move data from s3 to es using lambda in aws. I want to test my function however I think my file does not have the proper format, therefore, leading to an error.

My lambda function looks like this:

```
region = 'ap-northeast-2' # e.g. us-west-1
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
host = 'my-es-domain' # the Amazon ES domain,
index = 'lambda-s3-index'
type = 'lambda-type'
url = host + '/' + index + '/' + type

headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Regular expressions used to parse some simple log lines
ip_pattern = re.compile('(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)')
time_pattern = re.compile('\[(\d+\/\w\w\w\/\d\d\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s-\d\d\d\d)\]')
message_pattern = re.compile('\"(.+)\"')

# Lambda execution starts here
def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:

        # Get the bucket name and key for the new file
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']

        # Get, read, and split the file into lines
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        body = obj['Body'].read()
        lines = body.splitlines()

        # Match the regular expressions to each line and index the JSON
        for line in lines:
            ip = ip_pattern.search(line).group(1)
            timestamp = time_pattern.search(line).group(1)
            message = message_pattern.search(line).group(1)

            document = { "ip": ip, "timestamp": timestamp, "message": message }
            r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=document, headers=headers)
```

I've configured test events to a file in my bucket correctly. When I test it outputs:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambdaPackage.py\", line 40, in handler\n    ip = ip_pattern.search(line).group(1)\n"
  ]
}
```

Which I believe is problem with my file.
my file is in sample.log file and looks like:

```
12.345.678.90 - [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "PUT /some-file.jpg"
12.345.678.91 - [10/Oct/2000:14:56:14 -0700] "GET /some-file.jpg"
```

How can I format it ex: use .py, .json, etc... this is my first time with aws and log Infos. Thanks in advance!

I've tried creating another file in such format:

```
12.345.678.90 - [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "PUT /some-file.jpg"\n
 12.345.678.91 - [10/Oct/2000:14:56:14 -0700] "GET /some-file.jpg"
```

which output the same error.

Comment: Elasticsearch input data must be a valid JSON, you should format the file you want to forward to JSON.https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html

Comment: by the way, instead of insert, each line to elastic use can use the bulk action which inserts multiple objects in one call .

Comment: so in s3 logs must be in json format? if not I need to convert it right?

Comment: exactly, i'll check your lambda shortly and let you know if there's any issue

Comment: Can you print document variable and share it with us?

Comment: Share one of your files, i want to try it out on my environment

Comment: I've states what's in my file above in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is because you try to POST invalid JSON. Before insert the data into elasticsearch you need to convert from Python to JSON object using `json.dumps(document)`

usage example :

```
import json    
document = { "ip": ip, "timestamp": timestamp, "message": message }
r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=json.dumps(document), headers=headers)
```

More about [Python JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp).

**Update:**

Looks like there was 2 issues:

1. Invalid JSON which fixed by using `json.dumps()`
2. The object was missing bytes and text strings. Looks like the lines read from s3 file are bytes and not strings. therefore,each line must decode into a text string (unicode), e.g. `data.decode('utf-8')`

From the docs :

> Return a string decoded from the given bytes.

More about [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode).

Comment: yeah but how should I format my file? so that function can get ip, timestamp, message for multiple logs.

Comment: Just like you did, try to add the `json.dumps` that should fix the error

Comment: and changing to json.dumps(doc) still gives same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722051/re-search-typeerror-cannot-use-a-string-pattern-on-a-bytes-like-object

Comment: Thanks but how would I add b in front of line in a for loop?

Comment: try to add `line = line.decode("utf-8") ` rigth after `for line in lines:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201369/discussion-between-amit-baranes-and-haneul-kim).

Comment: Thanks it worked by adding line = line.decode("utf-8") but could u explain why?