# Python script... TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

This is my very first Python attempt:
I am trying to take the info (API key) from the command prompt and enter it into Excel spreadsheet called "CalendarData"

here's the code in Main.py

#imports presets and scedule and team id's

```
 presets = pd.read_excel(fileName,sheet_name="presets")

from openpyxl import Workbook
book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active
API_key = input("What is the API key? \n")
sheet.append[presets.iloc[0,7]] = API_key   <--  "presets" is the name of the tab in the spreadsheet
book.save("CalendarData.xlsx")
```

Here's the error I am getting.

(env) C:\Users\Marta>python run.py
What is the API key?
u+QBLoEyLWGSHqDDdMk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Marta\run.py", line 1, in 
import main
File "C:\Users\Marta\main.py", line 56, in 
sheet.append[presets.iloc[0,7]] = API_key
TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Your code does not show how `presets` gets assigned.

Comment: #imports presets and scedule and team id's
presets = pd.read_excel(fileName,sheet_name="presets")

Comment: Try decoding your string input before passing it to the next function

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Can you please elaborate, I am not sure what you mean by "decoding"

Comment: Try to look at this and see if it's solving your previous error https://stackoverflow.com/q/31019854/16836078

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  Now I am more confused... Not sure if I should use sheet.append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here,
but if you desire to insert the value of API_key  to the sheet
I would suggest using "append"

if you want to insert the value of API_key to a single column you should use

```
 sheet.append([API_key])
```

if API_key is a list, and you want to insert each of its values to a different column in the same row,  you should first convert it to a list and then use "append"
like this:

```
newlist = API_key.split(",")  # converting API_key to a list 
sheet.append(newlist)         #inserting it to the sheet
```

if you want to change the value of a spesific cell you should use this line

```
sheet["A5"] = API_key # change the value of cell A5 to API_key
```

in conclusion
your code should look like this:

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook("CalendarData.xlsx") #opening an allredy exsisting xml file
sheet = book["presets"] #selecting worksheet named "presets"
API_key = input("What is the API key? \n") 
sheet["H2"] = API_key #changing the value of a spesific cell (for example cell "H2") to "API_key"
book.save("CalendarData.xlsx")
```

hope I could help,
in any case, if this is your first python attempt I would suggest reading the documentation of "Workbook", this package is very well documented and it helped me a lot when I first started using it
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html

Comment: Yes, it's one key, should be inserted to a single column.   Now I am getting another error. Thank you so much for your help                                        sheet.append[presets.iloc[0,7]] = API_key
TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment

Comment: now you are getting an error since you are calling a function with "[]" instead oof "()" ' but to fix your problem I would ditch this line all together and replace it with 

sheet.append([API_key])

if you want to set the name of the sheet to be "presets"
you could use this line

sheet.title = 'presets'

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Ohad. I am a lot closer now. However, when I just use the code you outlined, the key end up in the first column and the first tab is named "presets".  What I need is to place that data into the third tab (already has the name) and at this location API_KEY = presets.iloc[0,7]

Comment: what do you mean by " at this location API_KEY = presets.iloc[0,7] " 
Do you want the value of API_KEY to be inserted into columns 0 to 7 at a sheet called "presets"?

Comment: Ohad, yes I need to insert into the sheet called "presets", column 'H2'. I currently have this code, but it's not working                                                                                                
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    book = Workbook()
    sheet = book.active
    API_key = input("What is the API key? \n")
    sheet.append(presets.iloc[H2],[API_key])
    book.save("CalendarData.xlsx")

Comment: as for selecting the already existing sheet named " presets" you should use the following line 

"sheet = book["presets"]" instead of "sheet = book.active"

Comment: Getting an error:                                                                                                                File "C:\Users\Marta\main.py", line 54, in <module>
    sheet = book["presets"]
  File "C:\Users\Marta\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 288, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("Worksheet {0} does not exist.".format(key))
KeyError: 'Worksheet presets does not exist.'

Comment: when you said yesterday that "What I need is to place that data into the third tab (already has the name)", what do you mean by "already has the name"? 
do you want to change the value of the already existing XML file? 
because if so you are loading your workbook in the wrong way (also what is the name of the file you are trying to load? is it  "CalendarData.xlsx" ?) 

sorry for asking for so much clarification but I must understand exactly what you are trying to achieve for me to help you

Comment: Ohad, thank you for asking. I really appreciate your help.  CalendarData.xlsx is an excel file where I need to place API Key from the command prompt. The key should be written into the third sheet called "presets" in the location H2

Comment: ok I think I understand you now, I edited my original answer to fix all your problems, hope I could help, and I will appreciate it if you could upvote some of the comments that helped you :)